# Pandas - Sort order by Last Page Viewed

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics

Can anyone help me sort the order of last page viewed?

I have a dataframe where I am attempting to sort it by the previous page viewed and I am having a really hard time coming up with an efficient method using Pandas.

For example from this:

```
+------------+------------------+----------+
|  Customer  | previousPagePath | pagePath |
+------------+------------------+----------+
| 1051471580 | A                | D        |
| 1051471580 | C                | B        |
| 1051471580 | A                | exit     |
| 1051471580 | B                | A        |
| 1051471580 | D                | A        |
| 1051471580 | entrance         | C        |
+------------+------------------+----------+
```

To this:

```
 +------------+------------------+----------+
 |  Customer  | previousPagePath | pagePath |
 +------------+------------------+----------+
 | 1051471580 | entrance         | C        |
 | 1051471580 | C                | B        |
 | 1051471580 | B                | A        |
 | 1051471580 | A                | D        |
 | 1051471580 | D                | A        |
 | 1051471580 | A                | exit     |
 +------------+------------------+----------+
```

However it could be millions of rows long for thousands of different customers so I really need to think how to make this efficient.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'Customer':'1051471580',
    'previousPagePath': ['E','C','B','A','D','A'],
    'pagePath': ['C','B','A','D','A','F']
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am worried about the multiple possibilities. It seems that the reconstruction process can not distinguish, for instance, these two paths `Enter → A → B → A → C → A → Exit` and `Enter → A → C → A → B → A → Exit`. Are there other constrains in the problem?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is topological sorting, which can be achieved with networkx. Note that I had to change some values in your dataframe in order to prevent it throwing a cycle error, so I hope that the data you work on contains unique values:

```
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

data = [ [1051471580, "Z", "D"], [1051471580,"C","B"  ], [1051471580,"A","exit"  ], [1051471580,"B","Z"  ], [1051471580,"D","A"  ], [1051471580,"entrance","C"  ] ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Customer', 'previousPagePath', 'pagePath'])

edges = df[df.pagePath != df.previousPagePath].reset_index()
dg = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edges, source='previousPagePath', target='pagePath', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
order = list(nx.lexicographical_topological_sort(dg))
result = df.set_index('previousPagePath').loc[order[:-1], :].dropna().reset_index()
result = result[['Customer', 'previousPagePath', 'pagePath']]
```

Output:

```
|    |   Customer | previousPagePath   | pagePath   |
|---:|-----------:|:-------------------|:-----------|
|  0 | 1051471580 | entrance           | C          |
|  1 | 1051471580 | C                  | B          |
|  2 | 1051471580 | B                  | Z          |
|  3 | 1051471580 | Z                  | D          |
|  4 | 1051471580 | D                  | A          |
|  5 | 1051471580 | A                  | exit       |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can sort your DataFrame by column like that.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer':'1051471580','previousPagePath':['E','C','B','A','D','A'], 'pagePath':['C','B','A','D','A','F']})
    
df.sort_values(by='previousPagePath')
```

and you can find the document here [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work in this case